# Mongorestore failing locally on Mac due to 'error connecting to db server: no reachable servers'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, homebrew

Seemingly out of the blue, I no longer can locally perform any sort of `mongorestore`. Every time I run one now I get `Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`

Its very typical for me to mongodump a latest production database to my local environment so I can properly simulate the production environment in local development. This is now blocked, causing serious issues for fixing bugs in the production environment.

I'm running mongodb installed through Homebrew. Its version 3.4.

When I run `brew services list` it shows as running.

```
Name        Status  User          Plist
mongodb@3.4 started administrator /Users/administrator/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb@3.4.plist
```

I've tried passing in a `host` and `host` + `port` parameter, which doesn't seem to help at all.

What should I do next in troubleshooting this issue? Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my computer fixed the issue :p